# 'ModuleNotFoundError' when trying to import script from imported script

Tags: python, python-importlib

My folder structure:

```
ttsTacotron.py
Tacotron-2
|..
|tacotron|
         |train.py
         |synthetizer.py
         |...
|synthesize.py # imports hparams.py
|hparams.py
...
```

When I call `synthesize.py` directly it works fine, all of its imports get processed successfully. When I import `synthesize` in the `ttsTacotron.py` and call it, it fails on importing `synthesize`'s modules. Specifically, it fails on importing `hparams`.

`ttsTacotron.py`:

```py
import fire
import sys
import os

import importlib  
foobar = importlib.import_module("Tacotron-2.synthesize")
```

Tacotron folder in question is [this repository](https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2) but the issue is unlikely to be specific to it.

Remarks: I use importlib to handle having `-` in the subfolder. Can't really rename it for various reasons.

My goal: Be able to call `synthetize`'s methods & be able to import tacotron modules from a script that is in the root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, when running `ttsTacotron.py`, Python looks up all non-relative imported modules in the directory containing `ttsTacotron.py` (and in the system module directories, which isn't relevant here), yet `hparams.py` is in the `Tacotron-2` directory.  The simplest fix is probably to add `Tacotron-2` to the list of directories in which modules are looked up; this also eliminates the need to use `importlib`.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, 'Tacotron-2')

import synthesize as foobar
```